# Capitalize() not working in for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, capitalize

I am trying to capitalize() the words in list.

why does this work?

```
capitalized_words = [w.capitalize() for w in words]
```

but this does not

```
for w in words:
    w = w.capitalize()
```

Comment: How do you know that it does not work?

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer; this tells others that the issue is resolved and helps people find the correct answer more easily.

Answer (score 2):

This is because

```
capitalized_words = [w.capitalize() for w in words]
```

creates a whole new list, while

```
for w in words:
    w = w.capitalize()
```

mutates `w`, but **doesn't actually change the `words` list**.

If you would like to actually change `words` using a for-loop, iterate through the indexes instead.

```
for i in range(len(words)):
    words[i] = words[i].capitalize()
```

This will successfully mutate the list.

SIDENOTE: If you are going to delete elements from a list, DO NOT DO SO WHILE ITERATING OVER IT. This method only works if you keep the list the same length.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a value to `w` in the second case does not change the value in the list, but rather `w` is a separate variable that does not affect the values in the list.